# Widget to display json with code folding?

Tags: javascript, json, formatting, widget

I know I can format json easily with `JSON.stringify(str, undefined, 4)` but does anyone know a widget that will display json with code-folding?

This is for a spike I'm doing on a Jasmine port of the awesome [ApprovalTests library](http://approvaltests.sourceforge.net/)